# What is behind the recommendation to avoid NFS and SAN?

Tags: cassandra

I'm working through an issue related to Cassandra performance and storage systems.

There is this statement re: Cassandra storage recommendations on the Apache site: "In most cases, Cassandra is designed to provide redundancy via multiple independent, inexpensive servers. For this reason, using NFS or a SAN for data directories is an antipattern and should typically be avoided."

However, modern NAS systems that use SSDs and are connected via NFS using fiber-channel are extremely performant and provide mission critical Enterprise support and HA capabilities.

Can anyone provide more technical guidance re: what is behind the "antipattern" and "should typically be avoided"? Completely understand that NFS can very often be a performance bottleneck and result in delayed  reads / writes due to a shared TCP/IP channel. However, what if someone could almost guarantee that there would be a highly consistent level of performance? Are there more fundamental underlying issues about how Cassandra performs write operations at the block storage level (e.g. ext2 filesystem) that are related to the "antipattern" statement. Or is it more a general issue with inconsistent performance and not being able to provide a deterministic level of IOPS, etc. that is the core issue?

Comment: To me its bordering on asking for opinions.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking along the correct lines - and the advice is caveated with the word 'typically be avoided'. Introducing a SAN can reduce performance in comparison to a local m2,nvme device, but from a resilience perspective, the introduction of a SAN often re-introduces a single point of failure. The issue is primarily one of resilience and not performance (unless you are using NFS, and then yes, performance is a big problem.)

You mention that the SAN has HA, but do remember that it is every component from the node to the SAN which also needs that redundancy to have the same level of resilience, not just the SAN itself. Multi HBA ports used, potentially through different switches which themselves are on different power rings etc.

If you end up having multiple nodes using a single fibre switch and that fails, you have lost multiple nodes.

A SAN can be used, but in doing so, you should be careful to consider the resilience of the whole system holistically and work through every additional component (HBA, Fibre, Switches, Ports etc) between your nodes and the SAN to understand if you have added more chance of failures overall, and the potential for a single piece of equipment failure to impact multiple nodes at once. (If that is present within the system, the use of racks may help.)

Answer (score 0):

In previous years, the performance aspect might have been more relevant but regardless the main consideration for the recommendation against NFS and SAN is around the fact that they are shared.

One of the best attributes of Cassandra is not having a single point-of-failure with its nothing-shared architecture. If a node goes down for whatever reason, the rest of the nodes in the cluster continue to operate because there is nothing shared between them.

Cassandra nodes are designed to operate independently of each other so having something shared is not recommended. For example, replicating data to multiple nodes (replicas) provides redundancy but if the replicas store the data on SAN and the SAN goes down then all the data is unavailable.

Additionally, we recommend mounting commitlog on a separate volume from the data directory so that writes are not competing for the same IO as reads. But when those volumes share the same channel/port then it becomes a moot point.

We completely understand why organisations are desperate to deploy Cassandra on NFS or SAN. If you do, go in with your eyes wide open knowing the limitations and the disadvantages of doing so. Cheers!